# Converting a pandas dataframe to a list of lists for input into an RNN

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

In Python, I have a dataframe that I imported with `pandas.read_csv` that looks like this as an example:

```
Cust_id| time_to_event_f |event_id |event_sub_id

1       100             5 2  
1       95              1 3  
1       44              3 1  
2       99              5 5  
2       87              2 2  
2       12              3 3
```

The data are ordered by `cust_id` and then `time_to_event_f`. I am trying to convert this dataframe into a tensor of dimensions `[2,3,3]` so that for each customer id I have a sequential list of `time_to_event_f`, `event_id`, and `event_sub_id`. The idea is to use this as an input into an RNN in tensorflow. I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@curiousily/human-activity-recognition-using-lstms-on-android-tensorflow-for-hackers-part-vi-492da5adef64) so I am trying to get my data in a similar format.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the original dataframe `d` to customer-id centered series by setting a `Cust_id` index and then stacking:

```py
d.set_index('Cust_id').stack()
```

The result series will look like this:

```py
Cust_id                 
1        time_to_event_f    100
         event_id             5
         event_sub_id         2
         time_to_event_f     95
         event_id             1
         event_sub_id         3
         time_to_event_f     44
         event_id             3
         event_sub_id         1
2        time_to_event_f     99
         event_id             5
         event_sub_id         5
         time_to_event_f     87
         event_id             2
         event_sub_id         2
         time_to_event_f     12
         event_id             3
         event_sub_id         3
dtype: int64
```

Given this representation, you task is easy: take the `values` ndarray and reshape it to your target size:

```py
series.values.reshape([2, 3, 3])
```

This array can be fed as input to tensorflow RNN. A complete code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = StringIO("""
1       100             5 2  
1       95              1 3  
1       44              3 1  
2       99              5 5  
2       87              2 2  
2       12              3 3
""".strip())

d = pd.read_table(s, names=['Cust_id', 'time_to_event_f', 'event_id', 'event_sub_id'], sep=r'\s+')
series = d.set_index('Cust_id').stack()
time_array = series.values.reshape([2, 3, 3])
```